# webbrowser.open() breaks the link (python 3.7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

When I run

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://google.com')
```

in Python 3.7 it opens broken url in my default browser: `http://openurl%28https//google.com,new-window)`. When I run the same code in 3.6 it works as it should. Is it a bug in Python 3.7 or I have something misconfigured?

I'm using:

- Linux Manjaro
- Python 3.7.0 installed with pyenv (`env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared --enable-optimizations" pyenv install 3.7.0`)
- Opera is my default browser
- `webbrowser.get()` returns `<webbrowser.Opera object at 0x7f546c22ea90>`
- my [os.environ dump](https://pastebin.com/bUA5F5qV)

Comment: Which browser are you using? Looking at the source code, it seems like your Python3.7 tries to open the url using......Netscape or Opera??? https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/webbrowser.py#L281

Comment: Can't reproduce on Python 3.7 on Win 7

Comment: I believe it is the environment problem, since you manually installed Python3.7 (did you use AUR or manually compiled?). What is the output of `webbrowser.get()`?

Comment: also, what is the output of `os.environ`?

Comment: I added all this info in the main post.

Comment: This issue is fixed in the next Python minor release!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: [This issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue34019) is fixed in Python side. You don't need to consider this problem after the next minor release of Python. The following answer is still useful analysis though.

---

In Python3.6, `webbrowser.get()` will give you something like:

`<webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser object at 0x7f1e5373a048>`

But in Python3.7:

`<webbrowser.Opera object at 0x7f546c22ea90>`.

This means that in Python3.6 it will try to open the URL using the XDG standard:

`xdg-open https://google.com`

whereas in Python3.7 it would open Opera browser directly using [its CLI command](https://www.opera.com/docs/switches/#remote):

`opera -remote "openURL(https://google.com,new-window)"`

While I am not sure if this change is intended, both ways are supposed be correct. The problem is, **Opera's command line option is broken**. This is not a Python's fault, it's Opera's bug. (Try opending using the command above, you will see the same `http://openurl%28https//google.com,new-window)`.)

For a workaround, you can force opening the URL via the XDG standard, using [`register()` with the new `preferred` argument introduced in 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.register).

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register("xdg-open", None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser("xdg-open"), preferred=True)
print(webbrowser.get())  # Now you will see <webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser object at 0x7f1e5373a048>
webbrowser.open('https://google.com')
```

I hope it would help!

**Edit:** it looks like that Opera's bug is because they haven't updated the documentation after they changed the engine to Chromium. Opera works fine with the Chrom's CLI arguments. I [issued a change to Python](https://bugs.python.org/issue34019) to reflect that.